# Random number simulation in R

Tags: r, random

I have been going through some random number simulation equations while i found out that as Pareto dosent have an inbuilt function.
RPareto is found as

```
rpareto <- function(n,a,l){
rp <- l*((1-runif(n))^(-1/a)-1)
rp
}
```

can someone explain the intuitive meaning behind this.

Comment: this is more of a stats question

Comment: Oh okay so can you help me with it

Comment: Are you asking about what the R code does or the reasoning behind the PDF of the Pareto distribution? If it's the latter, you'd get good help on Cross Validated.  This may help: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Pareto/vignettes/Pareto.html

Comment: Where did you get this formula?  One piece of it make little sense. Specifically `(1 - runif(n))` should have _the same distribution_ as `runif(n)`.  And why not just use the `Pareto` package?

Comment: Actually i am preparing for a competitive exam and the package containing pareto isnt allowed

Comment: @DevanshGandhi is getting people to help you on Stack Overflow allowed?

Comment: i am studying for it not giving the exam currently so ya anyone can help to solve doubts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [well known result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868400/showing-that-y-has-a-uniform-distribution-if-y-fx-where-f-is-the-cdf-of-contin) that if X is a continuous random variable with CDF F(.), then Y = F(X) has a Uniform distribution on [0, 1].

This result can be used to draw random samples of *any* continuous random variable whose CDF is known: generate u, a Uniform(0, 1) random variable and then determine the value of x for which F(x) = u.

In specific cases, there may well be more efficient ways of sampling from F(.), but this will always work as a fallback.

It's likely (I haven't checked the accuracy of the code myself, but it looks about right) that the body of your function solves f(x) = u for known u in order to generate a random variable with a Pareto distribution.  You can check it with a little algebra after getting the CDF from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution) Wikipedia page.

Comment: One minor caveat - F() has to be an invertible function, i.e., 1-1.

Comment: True.  It's been a few years since I had to do any formal proofs. ;)